# Is there any way to make Linearlayout having children not clickable android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a linearyLayout having several linearlayout and some views.

I want to make the whole layout not clickable.

this is the the first part of the linearlayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/selector_timetable_row"
   android:orientation="vertical">
```

I first did inflating

```
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(~~, above layout);
```

And I did

```
 view.setClickable(false);
```

but it is still clickable
listener to the layout still fires when i touch the layout.

Comment: What if you just do not override the clickable event?

Comment: what do you mean by not overriding the clickable event?

Comment: clickable should be determined at runtime like in java code not xml

Answer (score 0):

You can disable touch event propagation with custom view like below:

```
public class CustomLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

    public CustomLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Use like this:

```
<{Here is package name}.CustomLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/selector_timetable_row"
   android:orientation="vertical">
```